# General Curry Function

Tags: javascript, funciones

Podría explicarme alguien como funciona esta función? Estoy estudiando currying (no se que traducción al español poseerá) y en una parte del libro enseña esta función como una curry function generalista (o una general curry function).

Me cuesta entender sobre todo los métodos que llama sobre el array en la segunda y cuarta línea. El método `call` no es exclusivo de funciones? No debería pasar un inicio y fin como argumentos de `slice`?
Además no se supone que el objeto `arguments` no puede ser llamado desde funciones anidadas?

```
function curry(func) {
  var fixedArgs = [].slice.call(arguments,1);
  return function() {
    args = fixedArgs.concat([].slice.call(arguments))
    return func.apply(null, args);
  };
}
```

Para entenderlo, el autor da un ejemplo de su utilización. Aún así no puedo comprender totalmente su funcionamiento. Pero lo transcribo aquí:

> *This can now be applied to a more standard divider() function that returns the result of dividing its two arguments:*

```
function divider(x,y) {
  return x/y;
}

divider(10,5);
<< 2
```

> *The curry() function can be used to create a more specific function that finds the reciprocal of numbers:*

```
reciprocal = curry(divider,1);
<< function () {
      args = fixedArgs.concat([].slice.call(arguments))
      return func.apply(null, args);
    }

reciprocal(2);
<< 0.5
```

Por si alguien le ayuda a entenderlo y poder responder mi pregunta, dejo el libro y su autor a continuación:
*JavaScript: Novice to Ninja - Darren Jones*

**EDIT**: Empiezo a entenderlo. En la línea 2, llama (`call`) a la función `slice` y le pasa como argumentos el objeto arguments (como es el primer argumento y como indica la función `call` será el objeto sobre el que se aplique la función, osea donde la estructura interna de `slice` tenga un `this.`) y 1, que al ser el segundo índice, se salteará la función que se le pasa como argumento a `curry`. Entonces todo el resto de los argumentos pasados a `curry` serán agregados a un array que es la variable `fixedArgs`.
Cuando se llamé a la función `curry`, esta devolverá otra función que son la 4 y 5 línea. En esta función, se llama nuevamente a `slice` a través de `call` y como solo hay un argumento (que es el objeto `arguments`), todos los argumentos pasados a esta nueva función serán agregados a la variable `fixedArgs` (mediante `concat` y luego a la variable `args`.
Finalmente la función devolverá el llamado (a través de `apply`) de la función originalmente pasada como argumento de `curry` con todos los argumentos dentro de `args`.

Y para generalizar y definirlo de una manera mas **teórica**:
La función `curry` como esta expresada aquí, permite llamar a una función sin la totalidad de sus argumentos, que luego devolverá otra función que espera los argumentos restantes en su invocación.

Answer (score 1):

## ejemplo

Voy a tratar de explicarlo con un ejemplo. Supongamos que ya tenías programada una función que abrevia un texto a n caracteres (para imprimir algo reducido), recibe el número n y el texto t. Podría ser algo así:

```
function abreviar(n, t){
    if(t.lenght<=n) return t;
    t = t.replace(/\s+/g, ''); // quita espacios
    if(t.lenght<=n) return t;
    return t.substr(0,n-3)+'...';
}
```

Supongamos ahora que querramos reducir un array de nombres a 10 caracteres con la función `abreviar`. Se puede hacer sin currificar:

```
var a = ['John Nash', 'Jhon Von Neumman'];
var aa = a.map(function(nombre){
    return abreviar(10, nombre);
});
```

Currificando se hace así de fácil:

```
var a = ['John Nash', 'Jhon Von Neumman'];
var aa = a.map(curry(abreviar, 10));
```

O sea aplicar a cada elemento del arreglo [o sea hacer map] la función abreviar con su primer parámetro en 10 [o sea currificar abreviar].

### respuestas a las preguntas puntuales

1) sí call es casi exclusivo de las funciones. Pero slice es una función. (digo casi porque se le puede agregar a cualquier objeto una función llamada call).

2) No. `slice` puede recibir principio y longitud o solo princpio (y entiende que es hasta el final. `call` recibe el objeto al que aplicar la función (this) y los parámetros que recibe. o.f(a,b,c) equivale a o.f.call(o,a,b,c)

3) `arguments` sí puede ser consultado desde funciones internas, lo que pasa es que `arguments` se refiere a la función más interna.